# Loop Cut was created not as expected

Tags: modeling

I'm new to Blender and I use [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EztmPOhnWwA) video as tutorial.Now I have a problem at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EztmPOhnWwA&t=315s) moment.
I do everything as in video, but I get this result, after pressing *CTRL+R* (created Loop Cut was too short, red line display, what I expect to see)

[image: My case]

Here is an example from video, how should it works
[image: Example from video]

How to fix it? I understand, that I can create Loop Cut on every cell, but I would like to know, how to fix it

Comment: Usually the loop cut stops when there are tris or n-gons since it only works with quads. Are there somehow doubled vertices by accident? Have you tried hitting A to select all then M > Merge By Distance?

Comment: Hello, there must be a problem with your topology here, the loop cut won't work if the loop meets a face with more than 4 vertices for example, but please share your file so that we can test:

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann, thank you, that is solution!!!

Comment: I sometimes attempt a loop-cut with no intention to complete it, as a diagnostic tool, to 'debug' topology :)

Comment: @RobinBetts : I don‘t know if it is allowed to misuse the loopcut in THAT way!!!

Comment: Like RB I also use loop-cuts to see the flow and understand my topology better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just take this here from the comments so that this question doesn't remain unanswered:

Usually the loop cut stops when there are tris or n-gons since it only works with quads. There could be doubled vertices somehow by accident. To get rid of them, hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select all then <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge By Distance*.